# Unable to find WinRT apps option in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I have windows 8.1N and visual studio 2013 community, I want to make WinRT apps but i see listings only for blank silverlight projects.

[image]

When I go to properties of "My Computer" I see the following window.

[image]

It says windows 8.1 in the "Windows edition" section but it also says only Windows 8(the big blue text). I know windows 8 does not have support for making WinRT phone apps, can someone please tell me what exactly is the problem here.

Comment: Make sure you've installed latest Windows Phone SDK and using updated VS 2013. [MSDN Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/04/02/visual-studio-2013-update-2-rc-universal-projects-for-windows-and-windows-phone.aspx)

Comment: I already have windows phone SDK 8.0

Comment: Which VS 2013 update you're on?

Comment: I am using VS 2013 update 5.

Comment: Give "Universal Apps" apps a try - I see it there in your screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite close. Just click on "Universal Apps" in the new project screen and you'll see the templates for Windows Apps without Silverlight based on Windows Runtime.[image]

If not, go to programms & features and modify your Visual Studio installation. Select "Tools for Maintaining Windows Store Apps" like below.
[image]

Comment: I tried Universal Apps but i only found  options for "Class library(portable for universal apps)" and "Windows runtime component (portable for universal apps)".

Comment: What's under "Windows apps"?

Comment: Mexiner, Under windows apps i see "Blank App(Windows)","Hub App(Windows)","Grid App(Windows)","Split App(Windows)","Class library(Windows)","Windows Runtime Component(Windows)","Unit test library(Windows)".